# Access HTTP server through Remmina

Tags: remmina

There's a certain HTTPS service at work that I can only access via logging in to a Windows server using Remmina, then start a browser on the Windows server. Is there a way I can "tunnel" (or "proxy") this HTTPS service through the Remmina connection, so I can run the browser locally, outside Remmina? Later I need to test a web client application that runs locally, on Ubuntu. I'm using Remmina 1.4.25 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (jammy),

Comment: Remmina can't 'proxy' connections like this, no.